# Панорамирование изображения правой кнопкой мыши в QGraphicsView

Tags: python, pyqt5, mouse-event

Всем добра.

Есть приложение, в нем переопределенный `QGraphicsView`, а в нем изображение. Необходимо по нажатию левой кнопки мыши на изображение, вызывать функцию `pixelSelect`, которая определяет цвет пикселя, по которому кликнули и его местоположение(В примере ниже, не весь код). При зажатии правой кнопки, необходимо включать режим `QGraphicsView.ScrollHandDrag`, для панарамирования. Понимаю, что алгоритм должен быть примерно таким. При инициализации - режим:

```
self.setDragMode(QGraphicsView.ScrollHandDrag)
self.mousePressEvent = self.pixelSelect
```

Затем, отлавливаем нажатие правой кнопкой и переводимся в режим:

```
self.setDragMode(QGraphicsView.ScrollHandDrag)
```

Пробую как-то так, но ухожу в рекурсию из за `self._photo.mousePressEvent(event)`:

```
def set_pixmap(self, msg, w_img, h_img):
    self._zoom = 0
    self.qImg = QImage(msg, w_img, h_img, w_img, QImage.Format_Grayscale8)
    self._photo = QGraphicsPixmapItem(QPixmap(self.qImg))
    self._photo.mousePressEvent = self.pixelSelect
    self._scene.addItem(self._photo)

def pixelSelect(self, event):
    if event.button() == 1:
        self.setDragMode(QGraphicsView.NoDrag)
        position = QPoint(event.pos().x(), event.pos().y())
        print position
    else:
        self.setDragMode(QGraphicsView.ScrollHandDrag)
        self._photo.mousePressEvent(event)
```

Помогите, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Подсмотрел решение [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15034627/qgraphicsview-double-click-events-and-scrollhanddrag-mode-item-issue), пришлось немного подправить. Все работает.

```
def mousePressEvent(self, event):
    self._dragPos = event.pos()
    if event.button() == QtCore.Qt.RightButton:
        self._mousePressed = True
        self.setCursor(QtCore.Qt.ClosedHandCursor)
        if self._isPanning:
            self.setCursor(QtCore.Qt.ClosedHandCursor)
            self._dragPos = event.pos()
            event.accept()
        else:
            super(ImgViewer, self).mousePressEvent(event)
    else:
        self.setCursor(QtCore.Qt.CrossCursor)
        super(ImgViewer, self).mousePressEvent(event)

def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
    if self._mousePressed and self._isPanning:
        newPos = event.pos()
        diff = newPos - self._dragPos
        self._dragPos = newPos
        self.horizontalScrollBar().setValue(self.horizontalScrollBar().value() - diff.x())
        self.verticalScrollBar().setValue(self.verticalScrollBar().value() - diff.y())
        event.accept()
    elif self._mousePressed:
        self._isPanning = True
    else:
        super(ImgViewer, self).mouseMoveEvent(event)

def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
    if event.button() == QtCore.Qt.RightButton:
        self.setCursor(QtCore.Qt.CrossCursor)
        self._mousePressed = False
        self._isPanning = False
    super(ImgViewer, self).mouseReleaseEvent(event)
```